# how to arrange the data in particular cell in table in EJS

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, ejs

I am trying to display the records in a tabular format on my home.ejs here, I have problem with the coding for displaying multiple records in a single cell which are associated with one particular record

Here I have 3 comments for one Task_Name , according to my code, records are displaying in each row means 2X3 total 6 rows are displayed but I need to display for one Task_Name--All comments need to display in single row then I get only 2 rows

Sorry for long explanation, please provide me the logic or solution

Current output

[image]

Expected output

[image]

output screen shot

[image]

EJS Part:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < status_info.length; i++) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= i+1 %></td> 
        <td><%= status_info[i].Task_Name %></td>
        <td><%= status_info[i].status_Name %></td>
        <td><%= status_info[i].Cmnt_Details %>
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

server.js:

```
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    var getQuery = "select * from table_info"        
    mysqlConnection.query(getQuery,function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err
        else {
            res.render('DashPrac',{status_info:result});
            // console.log(result.length)
        }
    })
});
```

Data i am getting from database

```
[ RowDataPacket {
Task_Name: 'Architecture Design',
Cmnt_Details: 'Trying to load the data in all the tables...',
status_Name: 'WIP' },
 RowDataPacket {
Task_Name: 'Architecture Design',
Cmnt_Details: 'Checked the details',
status_Name: 'WIP' },
 RowDataPacket {
Task_Name: 'Architecture Design',
Cmnt_Details: 'Testing is going on',
status_Name: 'WIP' },
 RowDataPacket {
Task_Name: 'Testing Plan',
Cmnt_Details: 'Teting plan to be prepared',
status_Name: 'InProgress' } ]
```

Comment: Please post the expected output

Comment: And whats your current output?

Comment: Task_name Status comments
AI                 WIP         not completd
                          complete in two hours
                          completed
Testing         Go live compled

Comment: Please can you modify your question ,post expected and current output there.

Comment: actually i am trying to display the table but i cont able to paste it here

Comment: See its tough to understand what you are thinking until you provide ,what you expect.

Comment: i  rearrange the Expected output can you please look it once for me...

Comment: it should be in single row what ever i have Task_name and its associated comments

Comment: can you post the data also ,you are sending from server,status_info  contents

Comment: yes i am sending form sever

Answer (score 0):

You would need to mofiy your query and result set to get this output. Here is a solution which could work for you.

server.js

```
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    var getQuery = "select * from table_info order by Task_Name, status_Name"        
    mysqlConnection.query(getQuery,function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err
        else {
            let prevObj={};
            let filteredResult=result.map(e=>{
              let newElem={...e}
              if(newElem.status_Name === prevObj.status_Name)
                newElem.status_Name="";
              if(newElem.Task_Name ===prevObj.Task_Name)
                newElem.Task_Name="";
              prevObj={...e}
              return newElem;
            })
            res.render('DashPrac',{status_info:filteredResult});
            // console.log(result.length)
        }
    })
});
```

Rest of the code can remain the same. It will achive the result that you need.

If you want to combine all the comments thats pretty straight forward with sql query.

```
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    var getQuery = "select Task_Name, status_Name,group_concat(Cmnt_Details) as Cmnt_Details from table_info group by Task_Name, status_Name"        
    mysqlConnection.query(getQuery,function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err
        else {
            res.render('DashPrac',{status_info:result});
            // console.log(result.length)
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks,i can eliminated the repeated values but i need to specify the comments in the single row i am edited my post with my output screen

Comment: I think what you want to do would create more issues while editing. I think it could be done easily by using foreach instead of map and storing the filered sets differently...

Answer (score 0):

I second @Dhruv's answer above , however if you do not want to do any change in your server.js , instead you want to play with EJS your code should be something like:

```
<% 
var prevTask_Name = status_info[0].Task_Name;
var prevStatus_Name = status_info[0].status_Name;

for(var i=0; i < status_info.length; i++) {  
    <tr>
        <td>
%>
<%= i+1 %></td> 
<%  if(i == 0 )
    {
%>
        <td><%= status_info[i].Task_Name %></td>
<%  }
    else
    {
        if(status_info[i].Task_Name == prevTask_Name)
        {
%>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
<%
        }
        else
        {
%>
            <td><%= status_info[i].Task_Name %></td>
<%      }
    }
    if(i == 0 )
    {
%>
        <td><%= status_info[i].status_Name %></td>
<%  }
    else
    {
        if(status_info[i].status_Name == prevStatus_Name)
        {
%>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
<%      }
        else
        {
%>
            <td><%= status_info[i].Status_Name %></td>
<%      }
    }
%>  
        <td><%= status_info[i].status_Name %></td>
        <td><%= status_info[i].Cmnt_Details %>
<% 
prevTask_Name = status_info[i].Task_Name;
prevStatus_Name = status_info[i].status_Name;
} %>
```